# What model can we use for sentence classification using the CSAbstruct dataset?

Tags: nlp, bert-language-model, sentence-transformers

Trying to train a model for sentence classification on the CSAbstruct dataset : https://github.com/allenai/sequential_sentence_classification/tree/master/data/CSAbstruct

Tried with RoBERTa base model but it doesn't work well.

Can anybody suggest a better performing model for this task and its associated hyper-parameter combination?